# How To Add Custom Field in Report ->Sales->Sales->Order Form In Magento

Tags: magento, report

I want to add new field in Report->Sales->Sales->Order->Form

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I understand that you want to "Add a new field - ORDER DATE similar to From date field"

Steps to achieve that:

> 1. Override the file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form/Order.php

By override, I mean create your custom module under /app/code/local/Namespace/Module

> 2. After line no: 56 add the below code block:

```
$fieldset->addField('order_date', 'date', array(
            'name'      => 'order_date',
            'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'label'     => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Order Date'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Order Date'),
            'required'  => true
        ));
```

> 3. So your function would look like below:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    parent::_prepareForm();
    $form = $this->getForm();
    $htmlIdPrefix = $form->getHtmlIdPrefix();
    /** @var Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset $fieldset */
    $fieldset = $this->getForm()->getElement('base_fieldset');
    $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

    if (is_object($fieldset) && $fieldset instanceof Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset) {

        $fieldset->addField('show_actual_columns', 'select', array(
            'name'       => 'show_actual_columns',
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('No')
            ),
            'label'      => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Show Actual Values'),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('order_date', 'date', array(
            'name'      => 'order_date',
            'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'label'     => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Order Date'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Order Date'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

    }

    return $this;
}
```

> 4. In case, you do not want to make it a REQUIRED field, make sure you have done this:

```
'required' => false //instead of true
```

Find the screenshot here: [Order Date New Field Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFMuZ.png)

Currently, I have given the "name" => "order_date", you might need to FILTER the collection to SHOW REPORTS appropriately.

Let me know if this helps.

Happy Coding...